# How to install apache commons library for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

`commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip` was downloaded from [commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) and extracted to folder with java `jdk/lib`. I need to import Stopwatch from this library. How to do it for IntelliJ IDEA?

Update:
 Why can't intelliJ just add pom.xml to existing project without trying to delete it?
 [image]

**Solved this way:**

Downloaded a lib from http://commons.apache.org/
  intelliJ > Project Structure > Dependencies> + > Library > path to lib from commons.apache.org

PS. Still looking for a way to solve this using Maven...

**Not solved with Maven:**
[image]

Cannot Run project. Have to probably I have to configure it somehow...

**1**

[image]

**2**

[image]

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you use maven or gradle for your project?

Comment: choose to "delete existing project and import". This isn't deleting your source code, just the intellij project files. It will recreate the intellij project files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or Gradle, then you can include the library as a dependency:

```
$ tree
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- test
    |           `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- test
                `-- AppTest.java

7 directories, 3 files
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>deleteme</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

IntelliJ automatically adds the dependencies to the classpath.

If you open the pom.xml file as a new project in IntelliJ, the dependency will automatically be added to the classpath.

**Edit**

Otherwise, if you edit your project settings in IntelliJ, go to the modules section, and then the dependencies tab. You can add your dependencies there. See [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: OK, First off I need to install Maven and configure it for Win7. Seems complex for first the time.

Comment: I edited my answer. It explains how to add dependencies to an intellij project.

Comment: Don't really understand how Maven will help... I got to point in intelliJ `> Depencencies> + > Library > New Library > Select Library type: **[Java or Maven]**`. What's next? What do I have to add to current project so my Stopwatch from `commons.apache.org` would start to work?

Comment: IntelliJ has really good maven support. If you delete your intellij project (not your source code) by deleting *.iml, *.iws, *.ipr, .idea files, and then just open the pom.xml file as a "new project" in intellij. File -> Open -> navigate to pom.xml then IntelliJ will set everything up for you.

Comment: Why I cannot `Run` project after installing Maven? Is my `Run configuration` broken?

Comment: This seems like a different question than the OP and should probably be it's own question. I'm not sure why this new problem would justify removing this as the correct answer for the OP. But just for reference, IntelliJ allows you to right click on a public static void main method and choose to either run or debug the method. This is the easiest way to setup your run configuration.