# Can't import ArrayUtils on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So when i try to do this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
```

Intellij highlights apache in red and says "cannot resolve symbol 'apache'"
I also get an error when my code runs:

```
Error:(3, 32) java: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
Error:(27, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ArrayUtils
  location: class com.company.Deck
```

How can I get it to recognize ArrayUtils?

Sorry if this is a very basic question.

Comment: first you have to check whether `org.apache.commons` jar is available on your classpath or not? if it is there then clean you project or reimport your project. Thank You :)

Comment: Please have a look at [**How to install apache commons library for IntelliJ-idea**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413957/how-to-install-apache-commons-library-for-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download libraries first, then import  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from: `https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi`

Decompress the file

When using intelliJ
go to file -> project structure -> Make sure you've selected "Modules" -> click in add new

Search in the dropdown menu for the folder you decompressed before

Select only the file similar to this example:

commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar

(notice that the version could change, and be commons-lang3-50.20.0.jar, that's ok too)

Click accept, done